# How to store hierarhy in JSON?

Tags: javascript, database, json, structure

How to store hierarhy in JSON?

I have the following hierarchy:

Hierarhy:

```
 1:Publish, "Long description of Publish service", is_default
     7: 7 days,  150
    14:14 days,  600, +200%
    30:1 month, 1350, +300%
 2:Premium, "Long description..."
    14:14 days,  150
    30:1 month,  600
    60:2 month,  1500
 3:SuperPremium, "Long description...", disabled
    30:1 month,  150
    60:2 month,  600
    90:3 month,  1500, disabled
```

where:

- "Publish, Premium, SuperPremium" - is services. 1,2,3 - service ids.
- "7 days, 14 days, 28 days" - is service parameters. 7,14,28 - parameter ids.
- Parameters depends from services.

The following image illustrates it:

[image]

Need lite and usable structure in JSON format.

What is the best way to represent this hierarhy in JSON?

Comment: I'm not sure [JSON](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) means what you think it means. There's nothing to design when it comes to JSON; it's simply a translation of data into a string format.

Comment: Why the downvote? Just because a question does not interest you or you already know the answer doesn't mean to say that you should downvote it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach:

```
{
        'data' : [
        {
            'ServiceId' : 1
            'Name': 'Publish',
            'LongName': 'Long description of Publish service',
            'OptionalFlag': 'default',
            'Parameters': [
                { 'Id': 7, 'Amount': 7, 'Unit': 'days', 'Cost': 150, 'Surcharge': 0.0 },
                { 'Id': 14, 'Amount': 14, 'Unit': 'days', 'Cost': 600, 'Surcharge': 2.0 },
                { 'Id': 30, 'Amount': 1, 'Unit': 'month', 'Cost': 1350, 'Surcharge': 3.0 },
            ]
        },
        {
            'ServiceId' : 2
            'Name': 'Premium',
            'LongName': 'Long description of Publish service',
            'OptionalFlag': 'disabled',
            'Parameters': [
                { 'Id': 14, 'Amount': 14, 'Unit': 'days', 'Cost': 150, 'Surcharge': 0.0 },
                { 'Id': 30, 'Amount': 1, 'Unit': 'month', 'Cost': 600, 'Surcharge': 0.0 },
                { 'Id': 60, 'Amount': 2, 'Unit': 'month', 'Cost': 1500, 'Surcharge': 0.0 },
            ]
        },
        {
            'ServiceId' : 3
            'Name': 'SuperPremium',
            'LongName': 'Long description of Publish service',
            'OptionalFlag': 'disabled',
            'Parameters': [
                { 'Id': 30, 'Amount': 1, 'Unit': 'month', 'Cost': 150, 'Surcharge': 0.0 },
                { 'Id': 60, 'Amount': 2, 'Unit': 'month', 'Cost': 600, 'Surcharge': 0.0 },
                { 'Id': 90, 'Amount': 3, 'Unit': 'month', 'Cost': 1500, 'Surcharge': 0.0 },
            ]
        }
        ]
}
```

**Edit: (formatting details)**

There are some formatting details that you are going to have to deal with in code and no structure is going to be able to circumvent that. Such as how you store the percentage surcharge values then apply math to calculate totals. I like representing them  using 1.0 = 100% personally. You are also going to have to handle the pluralization issues with units of time such as days and months.

Comment: And I made childs structures same as parent - with same keys: Id, Name,  Data. For easy parsing.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do something like:

```
[
   {
      "Service":"Publish",
      "Desc":"Long description of Publish serive",
      "Params":[
         {
            "Days":"7",
            "Desc":"7 Days",
            "Cost":150
         },
         {
            "Days":"14",
            "Desc":"14 Days",
            "Cost":600,
            "Extra":"+200%"
         },{...}
      ]
   }, {...}, {...}
]
```

Comment: Notice that since I put the services into an array instead of a collection that they are already indexed in the proper order. You could explicitly add an ID field as well, but I found it superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

JSON can be written exactly as you would any other JavaScript object. An example taking your sample case is

```
[
    {
        "publish":{
             "id":1,
             "description": "Some description",
             "text": "Publish",
             "enabled": true,
             "params": [
                 {
                    "days": 7,
                    "description": "7 days",
                    "cost": 300
                 },.....//and so on
             ]
         }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{
    "publish": {
        "id": 1,
        "desc": "Long description of Publish service",
        "state": 1,
        "params": [
            {
                "key": 7,
                "val": 100,
                "desc": "7 days",
                "pct": 0,
                "enabled": true
            },
            {
                "key": 14,
                "val": 600,
                "desc": "14 days",
                "pct": 200,
                "enabled": true
            },
            {
                "key": 30,
                "val": 1350,
                "desc": "30 days",
                "pct": 300,
                "enabled": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "premimum": {
        ...
    },
    "superPremimum": {
        ...
    }
}
```

where: `state` is 1: selected, 0: not-selected, -1: disabled

Comment: This is a great structure but it isn't technically json, it's javascript.

Comment: And that's because? It does not have quotes key names?

Comment: Missing a ton of commas too, technically invalid even for JS.

Comment: TheZ is correct, it's not even technically correct js either. Read the json spec, property names have to have quotes around them ... its a string based key/value pairing system. http://www.json.org/    

It's a technicality but it's important that the correction be made.

Answer (score 1):

```
[{
 prop1 : value
 prop2 : {
     level2Prop : value1
     . 
     .         
  }
},
{
 ...
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

One of ideas was:

```
       // default values
       {
        service:'publish', 
        period:7
       }

       // data
       {
        service:{  
                 'publish':{title:'Publish'}, 
                 'premium': {title:'Premium',    description: '...'}, 
                 'superpremium':{title:'SuperPremium', description: '...', disabled}
               },
        period:{ 
                'publish': {
                          7:{title: '7 days'}, 
                         14:{title:'14 days'}, 
                         28:{title:'28 days'}},
                'premium': {
                         14:{title:'14 days'}, 
                         28:{title:'28 days'}, 
                         36:{title:'36 days'}},
                'superpremium': {
                         28:{title:'28 days'}, 
                         60:{title:'60 days'}, 
                         90:{title:'90 days'}}
               }
       }
```